# Cropping an image to be bigger

Tags: java, image, crop, aspect-ratio

Is there a java library or (any library) that can be used to crop an image bigger?
The problem is: an image of any aspect ratio must be presented as a 16:9. 
Since scaling would distort the image, and we need to present the entire image (so we could not crop)
the solution is to somehow superimposed that image to a white background where the background is the one that will ajdust to the aspect ratio.
Or simply in other terms: "cropping the image bigger".
How to actually do this? Is there a neat way to do this using standard java or a library?

Comment: It would be better if you gave us some code to work with.  What form (classes) is the image in now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such library.

The basic algorithm is:

```
1) if aspect ratio > 16/9
    Create a new image buffer that is taller than the original but 
        same width and aspect ratio 16/9
    blat the image with a background (like white)
    draw the original into the buffer at right position.

2)  if aspect ratio = 16/9, do nothing

3)  if aspect ratio < 16/9 
    Create a new image buffer that is wider than the original but 
        same height and aspect ratio of 16/9
    blat the image with background (like white)
    draw the original into buffer at right position
```

If you give us your try at the code, someone can turn the algorithm into working code.